# CQ5 QueryBuilder if Property has a value or has no value

Tags: search, aem, query-builder

I am running a query like to do determine if the page has the given tag(s)

```
predicates.put("property","jcr:content/cq:tags");
predicates.put("property.and","true");
predicates.put("property.1_value","properties:style");
predicates.put("property.2_value","properties:style/color");
```

I also want to be able to get all results that have any tag or query on all results that have no tag.

What would I put in the value section to check for these constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `operation` parameter of the property predicate. Its semantic is described here: [JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.html)

Comment: Hi @Markus, can you please update the link? This one seems to be not available. anymore

Comment: I updated the link in my answer. It's been some time since I last worked with CQ/AEM. Thanks for bringing it to my attention, Catalin!